Cannot resolve symbol 'jacksonandroidnetworking' in Android project
I'm working on an Android application using the Fast Android Networking library, and I’m encountering the following error:
Cannot resolve symbol 'jacksonandroidnetworking'

Here’s a snippet of my MainActivity.java file where the issue occurs:
import com.jacksonandroidnetworking.JacksonParserFactory;


I’ve already added the necessary dependencies in my build.gradle file, but the error persists. Here’s what I have in my build.gradle:
dependencies {
    implementation ("com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2")
    implementation ("com.amitshekhar.android:jackson-android-networking:1.0.2")
    implementation("com.github.amitshekhariitbhu.Fast-Android-Networking:android-networking:1.0.4")
    implementation ("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.3")
}


Have you added jitpack.io to your list of repositories? https://jitpack.io/

I fixed this issue by simply removing:


import com.jacksonandroidnetworking.JacksonParserFactory;


AndroidNetworking.setParserFactory(new JacksonParserFactory());



According to its documentation, JacksonParserFactory is an optional library and is not mandatory for using AndroidNetworking.
https://amitshekhariitbhu.github.io/Fast-Android-Networking/get_request.html
